# Fluent way (builder style) of creating a Mockito mock with method stubs

Tags: java, mockito, builder, fluent

One of ways to create a Mockito mock in Java is to

1. create the mock
2. stubb the methods.

For instance like this:

```java
// this code is just a imaginary proposal 
private Properties emptyProperties()  {
    Properties myMock = mock(Properties.class); // 1
    when(myMock.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);    // 2
    when(myMock.size()).thenReturn(0);          // 2
    return myMock;
}
```

I would like to create this mock in a fluent way like this:

```java
private Properties emptyProperties()  {
    return buildMock(Properties.class) // 1
      .when(myMock.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true)    // 2
      .when(myMock.size()).thenReturn(0)          // 2
}
```

Is there any mechanism in Mockito itself which allows to construct mocks like that? Or any other framework which could facilitate this way of construction?

**EDIT:
Motivation with bigger example.**

Answering the comments, my motivation is to create a nested mocks in a fluent way.
For instance instead of code:

```java
        Questions.QuestionItem item = mock(Questions.QuestionItem.class);
        
        Questions questions = mock(Questions.class);
        when(questions.getItems()).thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList(item));

        QuestionController controller = mock(QuestionController.class);
        when(controller.getQuestions()).thenReturn(questions);
```

I would like to create something like:

```java
        QuestionController controller = mock(QuestionController.class)
                .when(getQuestions()).thenReturn(
                        mock(Questions.class)
                                .when(getItems()).thenReturn(
                                        Lists.newArrayList(item))
                );
```

One of the motivation is to avoid creating local variables, especially where there are more nesting levels and more methods to mock.

**EDIT 2**

After using implementation of @knittl the code looks like what I am looking for:

```java
QuestionController demoMock = FluentMock.mock(QuestionController.class)
        .when(QuestionController::getQuestions).thenReturn(
                FluentMock.mock(Questions.class)
                        .when(Questions::getItems)
                        .thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList(
                             mock(Questions.QuestionItem.class)))
                        .returnMock())
        .returnMock();
```

I just wonder if there is any library which supports this kind of FluentMock out of the  box?

Comment: I can't find anything to suggest it's possible with Mockito. There is [one-liner stubs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#24) but you can only use that with a single stubbed method. If you could use Kotlin instead of Java, then use can use Mockk, which has exactly the kind of thing you are asking for.

Comment: Not aware of any such method. Probably it doesn't exist, given how Mockito records stubbing calls and needs to rely on the values on the stack and the methods being called in the right order.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? What's the benefit of this approach? Saving a single line?

Comment: @knittl those are not valid reasons for not having such a fluent interface. All you need is a `buildMock` method that takes a functional interface argument, whose parameter is the mock object, which you can pass as a lambda. You can even write one yourself. However, your second question is valid: "why do you want to do this?" I agree that having such as `buildMock` method wouldn't buy you much.

Comment: @k314159 sure, but how is `buildMock(MyClass.class).stub(mock -> when(mock.method1()).thenReturn(value1)).stub(mock -> when(mock.method2()).thenReturn(value2)).returnMock()` better than 4 regular statements?

Comment: I was thinking more like `var myMock = buildMock(MyClass.class, mock -> { when (mock.method1()).thenReturn(value1); when (mock.method2).thenReturn(value2); });` It's not actually fluent, but it does create a one-liner with multiple stubs. Still, it doesn't look like much of an advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and updates. I have simplified the example, just to show the essence of my question/issue. Answring your questions one of the motivation is to avoid creating local variables. I  have updated the questions with potential example.

Comment: Don't create new mocks while stubbing an existing mock, this is destined to break in very weird ways (have fun debugging!).

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic for Stackoverflow: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more: This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: @knittl thanks for citing the rules, but just out of curiosity, can you tell me how my question can lead to " opinion-based answers" ?

Comment: @fascynacja "Which library should I use to do X?" – "Use library A". "No, library B is better". "I have used library C with great success, library A sucks". "I wrote library D, you should use it".

Comment: I did not ask which library is better, I have asked which library includes solution. Also its not question like: "I want to create web app, which JS library should I use?" The problem is defined very precise. I have seen many quetions in SO stated like that and having normal answer. Either the library "has" the solution or "not". If you think the question violates the rules you can flag it.

Comment: @fascynacja asking "How can Mockito be used in a fluent way?" is fine, asking "Which fluent Mockito libraries exist?" is not. There is no library that I'm aware of, so you have to go with a custom implementation (which is provided by the answer to the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a benefit in avoiding a single line (you are not really saving lines anyway), but if you must do it, the following could be one way to do it. It is a thin wrapper around a Mockito mock object that allows applying a configuration to the mock object, then returns itself.

```
public class FluentMock<M> {

    private final M mock;

    private FluentMock(final M mock) {
        this.mock = mock;
    }

    public static <M> FluentMock<M> mock(final Class<M> cls) {
        return new FluentMock<>(Mockito.mock(cls));
    }

    public FluentMock<M> stub(final Consumer<? super M> stubber) {
        stubber.accept(mock);
        return this;
    }

    public M returnMock() {
        return mock;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Test
void fluent_expression() {
    final DemoClass demoMock = FluentMock.mock(DemoClass.class)
            .stub(mock -> when(mock.getName()).thenReturn("skynet"))
            .stub(mock -> when(mock.getAge()).thenReturn(666))
            .returnMock();

    assertThat(demoMock.getName()).isEqualTo("skynet");
    assertThat(demoMock.getAge()).isEqualTo(666);
}

@Test
void fluent_statement() {
    final DemoClass demoMock = FluentMock.mock(DemoClass.class)
            .stub(mock -> {
                when(mock.getName()).thenReturn("skynet");
                when(mock.getAge()).thenReturn(666);
            })
            .returnMock();

    assertThat(demoMock.getName()).isEqualTo("skynet");
    assertThat(demoMock.getAge()).isEqualTo(666);
}
```

Not sure if that's what you were hoping for.

---

Alternatively, go full overboard and add all methods (that you need) from [`OngoingStubbing`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html):

```
public class FluentMock<M> {

    private final M mock;

    private FluentMock(final M mock) {
        this.mock = mock;
    }

    public static <M> FluentMock<M> mock(final Class<M> cls) {
        return new FluentMock<>(Mockito.mock(cls));
    }

    public FluentMock<M> stub(final Consumer<? super M> stubber) {
        stubber.accept(mock);
        return this;
    }

    public <T> FluentStubber<T> when(final Function<? super M, T> call) {
        return new FluentStubber<>(call);
    }

    public M returnMock() {
        return mock;
    }

    public final class FluentStubber<T> {
        private final Function<? super M, T> call;

        private FluentStubber(final Function<? super M, T> call) {
            this.call = call;
        }

        public FluentMock<M> thenReturn(final T value) {
            Mockito.when(call.apply(mock)).thenReturn(value);
            return FluentMock.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would then look like this:

```
@Test
void fluent_stubbing() {
    final DemoClass demoMock = FluentMock.mock(DemoClass.class)
            .when(DemoClass::getName).thenReturn("skynet")
            .when(DemoClass::getAge).thenReturn(666)
            .returnMock();

    assertThat(demoMock.getName()).isEqualTo("skynet");
    assertThat(demoMock.getAge()).isEqualTo(666);
}
```

Caveat: this doesn't allow you to add multiple stubbings to a single method, so you cannot do `when(DemoClass::getName).thenReturn("skynet").thenReturn("T-800")` with this kind of fluent builder (you'd have to go the `stub(mock -> ...)` route or just use plain Mockito)

Comment: This is a gret piece of code I like the second option because its easier to read and understand. The first one with additiional "stub" is too much hussle in my opinion and adds unnecessary code which makes it more difficult to read. Probably to use methods like thenThrow  I will have to add them to the FluentMock I guess? I tiwll be cool to find library which already has this functionality also.

Comment: @fascynacja Yes, you have to add all methods which you want to use and delegate to Mockito. There is no builtin way in Mockito. As such, does this answer your question, i.e. "Is there any mechanism in Mockito itself which allows to construct mocks like that? Or any other framework which could facilitate this way of construction?"? Don't change the core points of your question after you have received answers